# WKWebView not executing any js code

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, gcdwebserver

I am rendering a local index.html file inside my Xcode project, using `WKWebView`. The thing is, the html and css code inside the file are successfully displayed inside the webView, but the `javaScript` however, is not rendered at all.

I have searched similar questions on this issue on stackoverflow and what I came up with is that Apple does not execute js in a local html file, and in order to execute js I am required to use a local webserver using `GCDWebServer`.

To be honest I am new to the hole webServer concept and I'm finding it hard to figure how to run the html in a local webServer and how to this with `GCDWebServer`.

What's the simple way to run my index.html file on a local server inside WKWebView and how to do so

here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: resourceUrl!)
    webView.load(urlRequest)

    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [WKUserContentController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) and [WKUserScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript). I used  these to inject Javascript in the webpage but you need to separate the js code from html and load it from the bundle.

Comment: not through `<script src="file.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to create a `GCDWebServer` local server with js files  rendering successfully with `html` script tags and with **no** need for JS injections such as `WkUserscript` or `evaluateJavaScript`

my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import GCDWebServer

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate{


var wkWebView: WKWebView!
var webServer = GCDWebServer()

var contentController = WKUserContentController()


func initWebServer() {
    let folderPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www", ofType: nil)

    webServer.addGETHandler(forBasePath: "/", directoryPath: folderPath!, indexFilename: "index.html", cacheAge: 0, allowRangeRequests: true)

    webServer.start(withPort: 8080, bonjourName: "GCD Web Server")

}

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initWebServer()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController


    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
    wkWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
    wkWebView.uiDelegate = self
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(wkWebView!)

    wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: webServer.serverURL!))
}

}
```